# Balancing Weights

Tags: mathematics

Source: [Australian Mathematical Society Gazette Puzzle Corner 35](https://www.austms.org.au/Publ/Gazette/2014/May14/Puzzle.pdf)

> There are some weights on the two sides of a balance scale. The mass
>   of each weight is an integer number of grams, but no two weights on
>   the same side of the scale share the same mass. At the moment, the
>   scale is perfectly balanced, with each side weighing a total of W
>   grams. Suppose W is less than the number of weights on the left
>   multiplied by the number of weights on the right. Is it always true
>   that we can remove some of the weights from each side and still keep
>   the two sides balanced?
>
> Rem: Ignore the trivial solution of removing all weights from both
>   sides.

Comment: Are you interchangeably using Mass and weight or is it part of the trick

Comment: @skv, it's not part of the trick.  Mass and weight are interchangeable in the context of this puzzle.

Comment: That seemed really easy to disprove at first but every time I try I find something that doesn't quite work. :)

Comment: I removed my answer because was based on a wrong assumption

Comment: Not sure if I get it. If I have $N$ numbers. The smallest total sum I get is $N(N+1)/2$ (since all have to be distinct). This makes $N(N+1)/4$ for the smallest W. The largest product would be $N/2*N/2$. So how can $W$ be smaller than the product?

Comment: Oh, maybe that's just the answer to the puzzle :)

Comment: @Gerenuk, it is only impossible for W to be less than the product of both weights if there is no common weight on the left and the right.  E.g. if weights on right is [1,2,3] and weights on left is [1,2,3], then W = 6, and is less than 9, the number of weights on left*right

Comment: Yes, that why my question is also a proof by contradiction. I forgot, that I made an additional assumption in search of a counter-example.

Comment: Is the criteria that the masses on a given side have to be all different required? Is there an obvious counterexample for when you are allowed multiple of the same mass on a side?

Comment: Hi Mew, there is a small group of us who are finding sanctuary in light of recent events... please contact cyanide.net@gmail.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, because there must a mass shared by two weights on different sides.

Suppose for contradiction that there is no such mass. Then, the weights are all distinct. Let $a$ and $b$ be the number of weights on the two sides. At minimum, the total weight of the two sides is $(a+b)(a+b+1)/2$ when the masses are $1,2,\dots,a+b$.

Then, we have

$$2w \geq(a+b)(a+b+1)/2 > (a+b)^2/2 \geq 2ab  $$

where the last inequality follows from being equivalent to $(a-b)^2/2 \geq 0$. But this contradicts the statement that $w<ab$.